# Pandas: Groupby and iterate with conditionals within groups?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by

I have a relatively tricky iteration question that I am having trouble implementing.

I have a dataframe with the first 6 columns seen below. I am trying to write a function that iterates within groups -- specifically grouping rows by Category and Level -- and then generates a new variable if two conditions are met for that row vs. **any other row in the group**. I'd like to generate the Opportunity? binary indicator below, where it equals 1 if it matches the condition. The Reason column just provides an explanation of the result I want to generate.

*Logic:For each id_group, if ((metric_LHS[entity]>Metric_RHS[other entity in group]) & (metric_LHS[entity]>Baseline[entity])), Opportunity? = 1*

So in my example, the Opportunity? column equals 1 for Jim because Metric_LHS(Jim) > Metric_RHS(Jack) and Metric_LHS(Jim)>Baseline(Jim). Meanwhile, Rick is a 0, for example, because the criteria does not work for the only other person in the group, Joe.

See below for some pieces of the code and logic that I have written. My question is the following: How do I iterate within each row of each group and compare that row with every other row in that group?

```
id_group=df.groupby(['Category','Level'])
    for row in id_group:
       df['Opportunity?'](([df[metric_LHS][row]>df[Metric_RHS][row+1]) &\
       (df[metric_LHS][row]>df[Baseline][row])) = 1  
***How to iterate to next row in group?***
```

[image: Example data]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When iterating this way over a groupby object, the returned object will be a tuple (`index`, `group`).

To iterate over the rows for each `group`, you could use [`DataFrame.itterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

Something like this:

```
id_group=df.groupby(['Category','Level'])

for g_idx, group in id_group:
    for r_idx, row in group.iterrows():
        if (((row['Metric_LHS'] > group['Metric_RHS']).any())
             & (row['Metric_LHS'] > row['Baseline'])):
            df.loc[r_idx, 'Opportunity?'] = 1
```

#### Working example with your provided toy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jim', 'Jack', 'Greg', 'Alex', 'Steve', 'Jack', 'Rick', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Dave', 'Dan'],
        'Category':['South']*3 + ['North']*3 + ['West']*3 + ['East']*2,
        'Level': [1,1,2,2.5,2.5,2.5,3,3,3.25,4,4],
        'Metric_LHS': [100,80,70,110,90,105,110,111,90,87,83],
        'Metric_RHS': [120,90,75,115,95,110,112,113,95,90,85],
        'Baseline': [95,np.nan,73,112,85,103,105,112,93,75,81],
        'Opportunity?': [np.nan]*11})


id_group=df.groupby(['Category','Level'])

for g_idx, group in id_group:
    for r_idx, row in group.iterrows():
        if (((row['Metric_LHS'] > group['Metric_RHS']).any())
             & (row['Metric_LHS'] > row['Baseline'])):
            df.loc[r_idx, 'Opportunity?'] = 1


print(df)

     Name Category  Level  Metric_LHS  Metric_RHS  Baseline  Opportunity?
0     Jim    South   1.00         100         120      95.0           1.0
1    Jack    South   1.00          80          90       NaN           NaN
2    Greg    South   2.00          70          75      73.0           NaN
3    Alex    North   2.50         110         115     112.0           NaN
4   Steve    North   2.50          90          95      85.0           NaN
5    Jack    North   2.50         105         110     103.0           1.0
6    Rick     West   3.00         110         112     105.0           NaN
7     Joe     West   3.00         111         113     112.0           NaN
8    Bill     West   3.25          90          95      93.0           NaN
9    Dave     East   4.00          87          90      75.0           1.0
10    Dan     East   4.00          83          85      81.0           NaN
```

Comment: This is excellent - thank you very much. If you don't mind further educating me, could you explain why you are dropping the groups in the if statement? that part is quite unintuitive to me

Comment: @Z_D No problem. I was actually working on an explanation for that step when I realised that it was completely redundant!  Basically, I was comparing the current `row` iteration against every OTHER row in the current `group` iteration - hence dropping it from the group. But this is only necessary if the logic were LHS `>=` RHS. It means the row will be compared against itself, but this won't matter as its not 'greater than' itself. I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you very much!