# Looking to find the sum of a unique member's payment based of whether some dates fall in between a certain time in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, group-by

this is my first time asking on the community although I have used the website for help extensively in the past. I was not able to find a solution on this specific problem and I am fairly amatuer at python so having a hard time putting the logic in code although I think the logic is clear enough. I am using python via google colab for this and have shared a google sheet with data at the end.

In my scenario, we have a start month, length of time, and payout month. End month can be calculated through length. A person can be a part of multiple groups and thus can have multiple start, end and payout months.

The goal is to find how much is expected to be paid by a member as off today.

eg group begins in jan 2020, is 10 months long and will end in oct 2020. The monthly contribution is 5k. The payout month is lets say mar 2020. While we technically should be getting 10 payments (10 month group) we will expect only 9 payments ie 45k because when the payout month comes around, the member is not expected to pay for that month. If say the group began in dec 2020 and if it was 10 months long, then as off today we would only expect 5 payments (dec to apr 21).

These scenarios get complicated for eg when a member is part of 3 groups, so 3 start dates, 3 end dates and 3 payout dates and likely 3 different instalment amounts. lets say the start dates are jan 20, feb 20, mar 20 and all groups are 10 months long. lets also say that there is a payout in apr 20. In apr 20, all the groups will be active (the end month has not been reached yet), so in apr 20 (the payout month) we will expect no payments from all the groups.

Meaning that, if there are 3 groups and there is a payout that falls between any groups start and end month, then we will not expect a payment for that group in that month. If there are two payouts that fall in between the start and end months of the groups then we we will not expect 6 payments for that month, 2 for each group and so on. If say 3 groups and 1 payout falls between the dates of only 2 groups, then we will not expect instalments for only those two groups (what ever the instalment is for those groups)

The following google sheet has some sample data.
The group ID col is entirely unique and will have no dups (you can think of this an invoice since all invoices are unique). The member code col can have duplicates since a member can have more than one group. Do not worry about the days in the date, what matter is the month and year. We have start month, group length and payout month. we also have how much money is owed monthly by a member for that group.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nAXlifIQdYiN1MWTv7vs2FqbFu2v6ykCzQjrJNPTBWI/edit#gid=0

any help or advice would be great.

EDITED -> I have tried the following but got an error: (i coded the months ie jan 2020 = 1, feb 2020 = 2 and so on so i dont have to mess around with dates)

```
deal_list = df['Group ID'].tolist()

def instalment(deal_list):
  for member in df['Member Code'].unique():
    if df['Coded Payout Month']>=df['Coded Start Month'] and df['Coded 
Payout Month']<=df['Coded End Month']: 
  count_months = count_months + 1
  return count_months * df['Instalment']

instalment(deal_list)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

EDITED - have also tried the following just now (took help from [Pandas: Groupby and iterate with conditionals within groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405670/pandas-groupby-and-iterate-with-conditionals-within-groups)). It sort of worked in that it gave me a count of 1 for each row. I was trying to get the number of times each payout month appears within the dates of a group

```
grouped = df.groupby('Member Code')

for g_idx, group in grouped:
    for r_idx, row in group.iterrows():
        if (((row['Coded Payout Month'] >= group['Coded Start Month']).any())
         & (row['Coded Payout Month'] <= group['Coded End Month']).any()):
              df.loc[r_idx, 'payout_cut'] =+ 1


print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While it's not part of the explicit guidelines @[ask], typically the expectation with SO questions is for the introduction to be succinct. The "[example]" principle applies to exposition, too. Consider editing to filter out information that isn't critical for understanding your problem and to integrate the code of what you've tried into your question.

Comment: have removed some off the noise!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. Essentially, rather than trying to iterate through all the rows, I transformed my data into long form first in Google sheets via transpose and filter (I filtered for all payout months for a member and transposed the results into the rows. I then pushed that into colab and through pd.melt transformed the data back into unique rows per deal with the additional payouts as required. Then running the condition was simple enough and finally summed for all true value.

I can explain a bit more of anyone needs.
I took inspiration from here:
https://youtu.be/pKvWD0f18Pc